# Returning Min date based on criteria ignoring blank dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to return the Min date based on criteria.

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Frank | 01/01/2014 |  |  | Susan |  |
| Susan | 01/01/2018 |  |  | Min | 08/01/2010 |
| Susan | 12/01/2021 |  |  | Max | 12/01/2021 |
| Susan |  |  |  |  |  |
| Susan | 08/01/2010 |  |  |  |  |

The following formula works fine in cell F2 as long as there are no blanks in the date column B. If there are any blanks it returns 01/0/1900

`=MIN(IF(A:A=E1,B:B))`

I found this solution that ignores blanks but returns the Min date from the entire column, not based on any criteria.
`=MIN(IF(B:B=0,"",B:B))`

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.14026.20202) 64-bit

Comment: Then use [MINIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the lucid and easily reproducible question. This should do the trick for you:

```
=MINIFS(B:B, A:A, E1, B:B, "<>")
```

It ensures that empty date cells corresponding to the given name are not considered.